# Extract date and time into timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL with columns new_date and new_time. I created a new column new_timestamp, now I need to extract date from new_date and time from new_time and insert into new_timestamp.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add extra two columns in table right

Comment: @Craig Ringer, I am looking for a solution in PostgreSQL. Thanks

Comment: What are the column types of new_date and new_time? It would help if you posted the table structure.

Comment: @Karthik, no. I have date, time and timestamp columns with more than 100 records, i want to insert date and time into timestamp(which is a new column) just by a sql query. Thanks.

Comment: @patrick, for date= date for time= time without time zone for timestamp=timestamp without time zone, Thanks.

Comment: Please post the *complete* `create table` statement (**edit** your question, don't post code in comments)

Comment: Re-posted as http://stackoverflow.com/q/31070593/398670

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET new_timestamp = new_date + new_time;
```

Comment: I am getting the this error. "cannot cast type time without time zone to timestamp without time zone" Thanks.

Comment: Thanks all, the solution is: update ucits.tradeticket
   set tradetime=(cast(trade_date as timestamp) + trade_time)